# Chromium-based browsers refuse SSL certificate

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, ssl-certificate

When accessing https://www.twitch.tv on Chromium-based browsers (new Edge, Google Chrome, Opera) the following (commonly known) error appears:

```
Your connection isn't private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.twitch.tv (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).
NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED
```

When checking the SSL certificate, it states that is valid until June 13th, 2020. However, it also states that the certificate is withdrawn by the certificate authority.

Accessing the site from Firefox and from Chrome on another PC both work fine. Several SSL check websites also state that the certificate is fine.

I already tried the following:

- Check date, time and timezone
- Clear cookies and cache of the browser
- Clear SSL state in internet options
- Clear DNS cache
- Temporarily disable anti-virus and windows defender

[image: Chrome Error]

Comment: I have no problem accessing that URL in a current Chrome, and neither of the two SSL checkers I put the URL into said it was revoked either (explicitly said that it _wasn’t_ even.)

Comment: @CBroe it's a curious issue. Accessing the website with Google Chrome on another PC also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

After an extensive search, I found a solution that worked for me. For those who have a similar problem: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/24475945?hl=en